# Какие слова могут иметь несколько начальных форм?

Tags: выбор-слова

Некоторые слова (здесь "слово" употребляется в значении "осмысленный набор букв") могут иметь несколько начальных форм. Например, слово "села" может иметь форму "сесть" (она села), а может иметь форму "село" (они выехали из села). Аналогично для слова "три": это слово может быть числительным ("3"), а может быть глаголом ("тереть"). Однако, это единственные подобные слова, которые я смог найти.

Вопрос: как много таких слов? Это единичные случаи, или таких слов десятки, сотни, или тысячи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы имеете в виду [омоформы](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/leksika/chto-takoe-omoformyi.html), если я правильно понял. Навскидку: пила (гл. пить; сущ. пила); дела (гл. девать; сущ. дело); дуло (гл. дуть; сущ. дуло);

Существуют словари омонимов, по которым, думаю, можно подсчитать число таких слов в языке. Например homonyms.ru, который включает также омофоны, омографы и омоформы.

В предисловии к нему сказано

> **Подобных слов с одинаковым написанием и разным значением в русском
>   языке довольно много**, что становится главной проблемой для их усвоения
>   и запоминания. Словарь омонимов поможет учащимся найти и использовать
>   слова омонимы в любой момент, достаточно иметь под рукой гаджет с
>   доступом в интернет.

Comment: Да, мой вопрос можно свести к поиску омоформ